# Proof of $|x|^{-\alpha} \in W^{1,p}(U)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

$U = B(0,1)$, the open unit ball in
$\mathbb{R}^n$ and $$   u(x) = |x|^{\alpha}$$
for $x \neq 0 $. And $u(0) := 0$. For which values of $\alpha < 0,n,p$ does $u$ belong to $W^{1,p}(U)$? (Here $W^{k,p}(U)$ is the Sobolev space on $U$.)

I'm guessing the solution should be $\alpha -1 > -d/p$. Here's my attempt:

$$\int_{B_1} u\phi = \int_{B_1-B_\epsilon} u\phi + \int_{B_\epsilon}u\phi.$$

And how do we go from here? My plan was to use integral by parts on the first term on the RHS and let $\epsilon$ goes to zero, so the second term should disappear, but I don't think it works with the integral by parts. Thanks.

Comment: How did you guess the solution correctly? Use $\nabla u(x) = \alpha|x|^{\alpha - 2}x$.

Comment: @Kakashi we know that $\alpha > d/p$ happens if and only if $|x|^{\alpha} \in L^p(B_1(0))$. And if we differentiate its not too difficult to guess that $\alpha -1 > d/p$ is a good candidate for the solution. I'm confused about the use of integral by parts, is there no other way?

Comment: $u \in W^{1, p}(U)$ means $u, \nabla u \in L^p(U)$. So you just check when $u, \nabla u \in L^p(U)$.

Comment: @Kakashi I still need to check that $\nabla u$ indeed is the weak derivative of $u$ in $U$, but here it seems like I need to use integration by parts, is there another alternative?